# Maven ressource filtering with M2E and external properties file

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have a maven projekt which reads an external properties file to filter the ressources. This works fine when using mvn package but starting from JUnit tests this does only work if the properties are declared in the pom itself instead of the properties file so i think the plugin configuration is the problem. I got this in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        <pluginExecutions>
          <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <versionRange>[1.0-alpha-2,)</versionRange>
              <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
              </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
              <execute />
            </action>
          </pluginExecution>
        </pluginExecutions>
      </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>${build.properties.file}</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The lifecycle is sill marked red in Eclipse.

EDIT:

The m2e part needs to be surrounded by plugin management and than the error is gone. I Can see the goal now beeing executed under the Maven preferences.

But its actually still not filtering the ressources when executing the unit tests from eclipse if I use this plugin. So this is still open ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear when you say that it works fine when you run `mvn package` because package will run test cases.
So my assumption is probably package is running properly by skipping tests.
In order to pass on properties to test cases you can use surefire plugin as shown below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemProperties>
        <property>
          <name>filePath</name>
          <value>/path/to/the/file</value>
        </property>
      </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This will pick properties and pass on to test cases.

Comment: maybe it was a little unclear: The tests run fine if I use Maven to build/test but not from IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try including the lifecycle-mapping plugin in a block like the following.  I've done this with other Maven plugins that do not have Eclipse connectors with success.

```
    <profile>
      <!-- Contents of this profile are only needed to make this project work in       
           Eclipse. Once all appropriate m2e connectors are available, this can be
           removed -->
        <id>m2e</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>m2e.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
          <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <!-- other plugin config here ->
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
          </pluginManagement>
        </build>
      </profile>
```

---

EDIT: Okay, you now have a green build in Eclipse, so try replacing the `<execute/>` tag in the config with this:

```
<execute>
    <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
    <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
</execute>
```

Then do a Maven --> Update Project again.

[Eclipse Wiki page on the topic](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really get what to do there ;). I copied the <configuration>...</configuration> part and now im getting a NPE while maven updates the project in eclipse. With just copy pasting your stuff nothing happens (which i assume is correct ;)) Can you please provide me with more info about this?

Comment: Ah ok i got it just some mistake... This is actually making it green but in lifecycle but its still not working ;)